# Is there any way to disable autocorrect in microsoft edge?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge, autocorrect

I'm using MS Edge and even though I have globally disabled autocorrect because it just gets in the way, it just does not care. It still insists on destroying proper capitalisation and otherwise wreaking havok on any text I enter.

Does anyone have any idea how to force it to leave my properly entered text alone already?

Comment: Umm... do you mean "havoc"? Perhaps you need a different language pack.

Comment: The Problem is mainly the random capitalisation of arbitrary words. `Problem` is one of those. And no, I'm not even slightly interested in getting a slightly differently colored set of Trouble, aka. a language-pack.